# Is there a vector format for depicting continuous 2D polygons with attributes?

Tags: qgis, vector, ogr, parcel-fabric

I'm working within the QGIS environment and looking for a 2D continuous vector attributed editable file format to work with.

**My goal is to find a vector layer that has different features with no topological gaps nor overlaps among them. Is there a well-known file format that does that?**

This layer needs to have its geometry easily edited in respect with its topological constraints. I prefer no post-editing processes like ArcGIS' topological fixes. What I had in mind is something like the ArcGIS' Parcel Fabric type but with a shorter and easier editing process.

----Places I've looked in----

1. [OGR Vector Formats](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html) page.
2. [OGC® Standards and Supporting Documents](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards)
3. Dr. [Google](https://www.google.com/). With various keywords...

Comment: This could be useful to read as a background information even it does not show you a ready made tool for topological editing https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=ISO+Topology.

Comment: QGIS has a topological editing option for any vector format. All you have to do is enable this option in the snapping settings (2.18 and earlier) or snapping toolbar (3.0). https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#topological-editing

Comment: Thank you @csk! That's pretty much what I had in mind - a bit more rigid perhaps - but it's good enough.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer. Please accept the answer so future visitors to the site know it's worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS has a topological editing option for any vector format. All you have to do is enable this option in the snapping settings (2.18 and earlier) or snapping toolbar (3.0).

Description from [QGIS 2.8 User Guide](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#topological-editing):

> Besides layer-based snapping options, you can also define topological
>   functionalities in the Snapping options... dialog in the Settings (or
>   File) menu. Here, you can define checkbox Enable topological editing,
>   and/or for polygon layers, you can activate the column checkbox Avoid
>   Int., which avoids intersection of new polygons.

Topological Editing button on Snapping Toolbar in QGIS 3.0:

[image]